# Как узнать количество строк в первой строке?

Tags: android, java, sql

Есть таблица из 3 полей. ID name Age ID=1,2,3; name=qwe,asd,zxc Age=2,2;
Как узнать количество строк в столбце Age. cursor.getCount() выдает общее число строк, и это число идентично ID всегда. То есть будет равно 3. А мне нужно узнать количество строк в 3 столбце Age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(Age) from table where ifnull(Age, '') <> ''
```

Comment: Cursor cursor=database.query("MainTable",null,null,null,null,null,null);

Куда это именно надо вписать, не подскажите?

Comment: Попробуйте лучше для начала так:

    rawQuery("весь запрос");

Comment: Мой рабочий код: 

     Cursor cursor=database.query("MainTable", new String[]{"cocktailText"},"cocktailText IS NOT NULL",null,null,null,null);

Чо за ***

     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: Здесь почитай http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/76-urok-36-sqlite-podrobnee-pro-metod-query-uslovie-sortirovka-gruppirovka.html